# Spread operator is only inserting last item in the object in useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, es6-class

I've been trying to get questions from an API for my quiz website
I want to push the questions that are being returned from `processData` function inside the `questions` list that is in the `data` object.

When i added the returned items from the `processData` function in the `setData` it does not add all the returned items and only add the last one, I want all the items i don't know what is wrong with it.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    questions: [],
  });

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await axios.get(baseURL).then((res) => {
        const apiData = res.data.results;
        apiData.map((e) => {
          const questions = processData(e);
          setData((prevData) => {
            return {
              ...prevData,
              questions: questions,
            };
          });
        });
      });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: BTW your `await` does nothing here.

Comment: If you don't use the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool

Comment: What does `apiData` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add questions to existing questions, which you never do:

```js
setData((prevData) => {
  return {
    ...prevData,
    questions: [
      ...prevData.questions,
      questions,
    ]
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

...prevData was to read its previous questions value but you overrode it with new questions that you received from the API.

Here is the correct syntax:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    questions: [],
  });

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await axios.get(baseURL).then((res) => {
        const apiData = res.data.results;
        apiData.map((e) => {
          const questions = processData(e);
          setData((prevData) => {
              questions: [ ...prevData.questions, questions ],
            };
         );
        });
      });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```